# C# ASP .NET MVC The entity type [class_name] is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, database-connection

When I try to add object **question** to my database:

```
using (var dataTransaction = data.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
try
{
   foreach (var a in list)
   {
       list2.Add(a);
       counter += 1;
   }
   while (counter <= 20)
   {
       list2.Add(null);
       counter += 1;
   }
   var question = new Models.Questions
   {
       word_1 = list2[0],
       word_2 = list2[1],
       word_3 = list2[2],
   };

   data.Question.Add(question);
   data.SaveChanges();
   dataTransaction.Commit();
}
```

... I receive below operation exception:

*The entity type **Questions** is not part of the model for the current context.*

I've done lot of researches to solve this out but no solutions helped.

**1.**
I've added constructor with parameter "name = DataContext" from base:

```
public DataContext() : base("name = DataContext")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<DataContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<DataContext>());
    }
```

**2.**
I've added method OnModelCreating:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Questions>();
    }
```

**3.**
I've tried to change type od data, i mean fields word_1, word_2, word_3 in my database

**4.**
I've changed ADO .NET based connection string to EF Designer model connection string (and backwards):

**ADO .NET** based:

```
<add name="questions_answersEntities" 
   connectionString="metadata=res://*/App_Data.QuestionsAnswers.csdl|
                                      res://*/App_Data.QuestionsAnswers.ssdl|
                                      res://*/App_Data.QuestionsAnswers.msl;
                              provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
                              provider connection string=
                                &quot;data source=IGOR\IGOR_SQL_SERVER;
                                initial catalog=questions_answers;
                                integrated security=True;
                                multipleactiveresultsets=True;
                                App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
  providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

**EF Designer** based:

```
<add name="DataContext"  
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"  
    connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=QuestionsAnswers;Integrated Security=True;"/>
```

I have classes **Questions** inheriting from **DbContext** as showed below.

```
public class Questions : DbContext
{
    [Key]
    public int id_question { get; set; }

    public string word_1 { get; set; }
    public string word_2 { get; set; }
    public string word_3 { get; set; }
}
```

I have also class **DataContext** inheriting from **DbContext**:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext() : base("name = DataContext")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<DataContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<DataContext>());
    }

    public DbSet<Questions> Question { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Answers> Answers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Questions>();
    }
}
```

5. I've also tried to use data.Entry(question) instead of data.Question.Add(question) and the same error exception appears.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. I've realised that connection string concerning object *data* is not valid and is the default connection string pointing on *LocalDb*.
In the HomeController, in the scope of

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
```

I've changed construction:

`using ( var data = new Models.DataContext())`

to

`var data = new Models.DataContext();`

and I've added manifestly attribution *connection string* to *data* as follwing:

```
data.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = @"data source=IGOR\IGOR_SQL_SERVER;" + 
                "initial catalog = questions_answers;" + "integrated security = True;" + 
                "MultipleActiveResultSets = True;";
```

After this data I am able to save data in my database.